# Age of Decadence how to kill guy in training?

Tags: the-age-of-decadence

I am doing a training mission for the Age of Decadence and my god it is hard. I am using equipment that I have been given. Guy that I am supposed to defeat wipes the floor with me every time. I barely manage to hit him once or twice for one or two damage throughout the battle and he destroys me without missing, hitting for ~6 for average causing bleeding.

**I don't stand a chance, how do I beat this guy?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things that I have missed, I have been playing without assigning my initial skill-points and wasn't changing my equipment.

I have added 4 to Spears 4 to dodge and 4 to critical and 2 to block.

I then picked up helmet that does not reduce To Hit Chance and armour that adds 7 Damage Resist and only has 16 Armour penalty (25 would be normal). And I used light spear that on normal attack uses 5AP and has increased chance to hit.

Strategy I used is to push him and hit twice in one round, this way I managed to kill mercenary with 25 out of 50 HP points left.

Here's a video:

Hope this saves you some time.